# How to turn the Pascal triangle upside down in C, so the first row is printed last, and the last row is printed first?

Tags: c

I've created a program which will ask the user for input regarding the Pascal triangle and then output it based on their input, and it works, however, I now need to make it upside down, so that the last row is printed first, and the first row is printed last. I've thought of 2 ways of doing it but not entirely sure how to execute them. One way would be to change the loops, as i've got 3 For loops, and they have 1 added on to them each time, so instead of adding 1, it'd subtract 1, however, I don't think this will work as it'd mean the starting value in the loop would have to be greater than the number of rows, and the loop terminates when the value in the variable is equal or larger than the rows. Another way I thought of is to reposition the printf function, but not entirely sure how to do that.

My code:

```
for (i=0; i < rows; i++)
```

Comment: Computing binomial coefficients via factorial is inefficient and quickly produces incorrect results due to overflow of the intermediate calculations.

Comment: In the Pascal triange, each number not on the edge is a sum of the two numbers above it. Try to produce the numbers this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `code` could work for three cases.

test: `./a.out 5`

```
case 1: 

                   1    
               1       1    
           1       2       1    
       1       3       3       1    
   1       4       6       4       1    


 case 2: 

   1       4       6       4       1    
       1       3       3       1    
           1       2       1    
               1       1    
                   1    


 case 3: 

                   1    
               1       1    
           1       2       1    
       1       3       3       1    
   1       4       6       4       1    
       1       3       3       1    
           1       2       1    
               1       1    
                   1
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return -1;

    char* ptr;
    int rows = strtol(argv[1], &ptr, 10);
    if (rows < 1 || rows > 10 || *ptr != '\0')
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int f[20][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        f[i][i] = f[i][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i != rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 1; j != i; ++j)
            f[i][j] = f[i-1][j] + f[i-1][j-1];

    printf("\n\n case 1: \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows - i - 1; ++j)
            printf("%4c", ' ');
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("%4d%4c", f[i][j], ' ');
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n case 2: \n\n");
    for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows - i - 1; ++j)
            printf("%4c", ' ');
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("%4d%4c", f[i][j], ' ');
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n case 3: \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows - i - 1; ++j)
            printf("%4c", ' ');
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("%4d%4c", f[i][j], ' ');
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = rows - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows - i - 1; ++j)
            printf("%4c", ' ');
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("%4d%4c", f[i][j], ' ');
        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've looked at your case 2 and mirrored the same in mine, and it works exactly how I want but with one problem, after the triangle is printed, it seems like the program is still waiting for input rather than ending and I have to close down the entire terminal. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @JohnCenaFanboi The line `long unsigned int i, j, rows;` change to `int i, j, rows;`, then it's ok.